# Need to pass all data field which bind in Ng-multiselect-dropdown through formControlName

Tags: angular

Multiselect dropdown only passes 2 fields id-field and the text field. But I need all the fields to pass through the form control name how can I solve this issue?

HTML

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
             formControlName="benefitId"
             class="form-control"
             [(ngModel)]="benefitId"
             [placeholder]="'Benefits'"
             [data]="BenefitList"
             [settings]="dropdownSettings"
           >
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Typescript

```js
this.dropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'benefitId',
    textField: 'name',
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
    itemsShowLimit: 1,
    allowSearchFilter: true,
};
```

BenefitList:

```
"Status": true,
"Message": "All Benefits fetched",
"Info": [
   {
          "benefitId": 1,
          "name": "Award Winning",
          "image": "**image url**"
   },
   {
          "benefitId": 2,
          "name": "Award Winning2",
          "image": "**image url**"
   }
]
```

Output:

```
benefitId: 
Array(2)
0: 
{benefitId: 1, name: 'Award Winning'}
1: 
{benefitId: 2, name: 'Eco-Friendly'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: 
Array(0)
```

Output needed:

```
benefitId: 
Array(2)
0: 
{benefitId: 1, name: 'Award Winning',image:'**image url**'}
1: 
{benefitId: 2, name: 'Eco-Friendly',image:'**image url**'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: 
Array(0)
```

How can I solve this issue? or is there any other option for multiselect dropdown which is easy to access

Comment: You has a formControlName and ngModel. You can use **never**  together both in the same tag. If you're using Reactive forms use formControlName, if you use Template driven form use ngModel

Comment: Okey....But what about the solution of above question?

Comment: if you remove the ngModel should be work. What version and library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code for get all data fields into a new array

```js
var datalistfromApi=[
   {
          "benefitId": 1,
          "name": "Award Winning",
          "image": "*image url*"
   },
   {
          "benefitId": 2,
          "name": "Eco-Friendly",
          "image": "*image url*"
   }
];

var selectedValues=[
                    {benefitId: 1, name: 'Award Winning'},
                    {benefitId: 2, name: 'Eco-Friendly'}
                   ];

// A comparer used to determine if two entries are equal.
const isSameUser = (a, b) => a.benefitId === b.benefitId && a.name === b.name;

// Get items that only occur in the left array,
// using the compareFunction to determine equality.
const onlyInLeft = (left, right, compareFunction) => 
  left.filter(leftValue =>
    right.some(rightValue => 
      compareFunction(leftValue, rightValue)));

const onlyInA = onlyInLeft(datalistfromApi, selectedValues, isSameUser);


const result = [...onlyInA];

console.log(result);
```